# Сборка библиотеки JS webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babel

Пытаюсь собрать библиотеку JS написанную на es6 в бандл. Для модулей используется import/export и пресет es2015
Либа имеет следующую структуру.

```
./src/
   Unit1.js
   Unit2.js
   ...
   UnitN.js
   Entry.js  //Точка входа
```

В точке входа собираю в пространство имен экспортируемые классы

```
import A from 'MyLib/Unit1.js'
import B from 'MyLib/Unit3.js'
import C from 'MyLib/UnitN.js'

export default {
    A: A,
    B: B,
    C: C
};
```

конфиг webpack:

```
{
context: lib_path,
entry: './Entry.js',
output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/dist`,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    library: 'MyLib'
},
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
            presets: ['es2015']
        }
    }]
},
resolve: {
    root: lib_path,
    alias: {
        MyLib: './'
    }
}
}
```

Проблема в следующем я могу определить пространство имен в конфиге webpack(output.library), но тогда для обращения к классам библиотеки нужно использовать конструкции  *MyLib.default.A* хотелось бы исключить слово **default**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем судя по всему webpack ничего не режет, и нужно просто правильно применить синтаксис es6-модулей.

[Вот очень подробная статья на английском.](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html)

Нам не нужен экспорт по умолчанию, нам нужны именованные экспорты, поэтому просто убираем слово default:

```
export {
    A: A,
    B: B,
    C: C
};
```

А теперь видим на это, и понимаем что можем применить [**es6-фичу**](http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand) которая позволяет кратко объявлять такие объекты и напишем просто

```
export {A, B, C}
```

Собственно такой формат экспорта можно увидеть очень часто. Там где предпочитают экспортировать модуль в одном месте а не по кусочкам.